# display profile image on navbar

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i am trying to make a user profile picture visible on the dashboard header after login

```
<a class="navbar-user__thumb"><img src="{{ getImage(getFilePath('userProfile') . '/' . $user->image, null, true) }}" alt="profile-image" width="50" height="50"></a>
```

this displays the picture on the home dashboard menu but when i change menu (which is a different blade with the same header ) i get an error message

> Undefined variable $user

i tried adding a check before the code but i am probably doing it wrong

```
@auth (auth()->user() && !request()->routeIs('user.*'))
                   <li><a class="navbar-user__thumb"><img src="{{ getImage(getFilePath('userProfile') . '/' . $user->image, null, true) }}" alt="profile-image" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                   
                    @endauth
```

i get no errors but the picture don't display
`

Answer (score 0):

You should use if statement:

```
@if (auth()->user() && !request()->routeIs('user.*'))
    <li><a class="navbar-user__thumb"><img src="{{ getImage(getFilePath('userProfile') . '/' . auth()->user()->image, null, true) }}" alt="profile-image" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                   
@endif
```

Or:

```
   @auth
      @if (!request()->routeIs('user.*'))
            <li><a class="navbar-user__thumb"><img src="{{ getImage(getFilePath('userProfile') . '/' . auth()->user()->image, null, true) }}" alt="profile-image" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
                           
        @endif
   @endauth
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#authentication-directives

> The @auth and @guest directives may be used to quickly determine if
> the current user is authenticated or is a guest

Comment: the 1st code      `<a class="navbar-user__thumb"><img src="{{ getImage(getFilePath('userProfile') . '/' . $user->image, null, true) }}" alt="profile-image" width="50" height="50"></a>` works and displays only on home dashboarb blade, but shows error on other blades sharing same header.blade....and when i add @if or @auth it doesn't display anywhere and no errors

Comment: Because you didn't login. Anyways, i edited my answer, I you want display image of authenticated user, use auth()->user()->image

Comment: logged in, the user  home dashboard is the only one displaying the user's profile picture, all other blades aside the user's home dashboard wants me to define the $user, but i'm already logged in, and like i already stated it works without `@if` or `@auth` only on the user's home dashboard after user logs in....i dont get it, same header.blade worked fine with the user dashboard.blade  but all other user blade give an error

Comment: Did you try my code with auth()->user()->image??